# Why Shrink/Flatten tool does not close this side faces automatically?

Tags: modeling

[image]

I duplicate the required faces to be expanded. I used circle selection option. But when i expand the side faces, sides won't close. I follow a tutorial on which it closes properly.

Comment: hello, could you please link the tutorial you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to extrude instead of duplicating your selection. Press E, right click to keep the faces in place then Alt S to inflate
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iB085.jpg